# passing array of pointers c

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I have something like following code sample:

```
char *list[5];
char * final_result[5];

for (i = 0 ; i <5; i++)
   liste[i] =  data->numero;
```

How can i pass list to a function and get back the result ?

```
final_result = removeDuplicate(liste , 5);
```

Function:

```
char*  removeDuplicate(char *liste ,int n){
   char* result[5];
   //code
   return result;
}
```

Note: data->numero contains char value

Comment: Asked so many times...

Answer (score 1):

Main code:

```
    char *liste_temp[5];
    char * final_result[5]; int count;

    liste_temp[5] = {'111', '222', '111' , '444' , '555');

    count = removeDuplicateRlt(liste_tmp , final_result);
```

Here i pass list of pointer array (liste_tmp) and get back the pointer array by final_result.

Function:

```
    int removeDuplicateRlt(char* liste_tmp[5], char *final_result[5])
    {
    //code
    return integer_value; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a function with pointer paramters or pointer results you have to design an interface. You have to specify

- who creates the objects the pointers are pointing to
- who has the ownership of the objects
- if the objects are modified in place or if you expect a news instance of objects

In your question you even not clearly designed the return value. It's a pointer or it's an array of pointers?

One example that would work

```
#define STRING_ARRAY_SIZE 5
typedef char* string_array[STRING_ARRAY_SIZE];

string_array input = { "A", "B", "C", "B", "D is also possible" };
string_array result;

result = removeDuplicate(input, 42);

string_array removeDuplicate(string_array arr, int unsued)
{
    string_array sort_buffer;
    int i, j;

    memset(sort_buffer, 0, sizeof(sort_buffer));
    j = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < STRING_ARRAY_SIZE; ++i)
    {
        if (check for duplicate )
        {
            sort_buffer[j++] = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return sort_buffer;
}
```

But this is just one idea. It might be wrong because you didn't specify the interface. The array might have a variable length. In that case you will create a result array on th heap and return a pointer to the object. But than you also have to return the result size.

*Edit*: Returning an array or structure is not possible with K&R C compilers. But with C99 you can return by value. This differs from returning a pointer to a local variable that would go out of scope on return. The compiler will memcpy the local variables content to the callers variable when you return by value. It's a job of the compiler optimization to avoid the memcpy and access the callers varibale directly.

Comment: I'd like to up-vote, but you can't return `sort_buffer` like that; it is a local variable that goes out of scope when the function returns.